# Mozilla Thunderbird: Displaying the originating email-address in full

Tags: thunderbird

I have two family members with the exact same name, I would like to sort them in my inbox by their email addresses (which are, of course, not the same). How do I accomplish this in Mozilla Thunderbird?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to do this would be to set up two search folders, one for each family member.

Right-Click on the inbox, use `From` `Contains` and their email address as the filter, then at the bottom choose `Save as Search Folder`.  Perhaps place the search folder under your inbox so they have their own inbox effectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with the [Show Address Only](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/show-address-only/?src=ss) Thunderbird add-on which might be easier to use and work better than setting up a permanent Search Folder.